# Precision loss when printing floats as strings

Tags: go, floating-point

It just happened to me that if I store int number into a struct and later apply division with them. The precision would be lost.

```
func main() {
   var x = 94911151
   var y = 94911150
   // If we use the value to calculate division directly, it would be fine
   var result1 = float64(94911151)/94911150
   var result2 = float64(x)/float64(y)
   fmt.Println(result1, result2)
   // If we pass the values directly as parameter into a function and then apply division, it would be fine
   getParas(x,y)
   // If we pass the values into a stuct, and then retrieve the value from struct, then apply division, the precision would be lost.
   getLinearParas(Point{x,y},Point{0,0})
}

func getParas(a int, b int){
    diffX := a -0
    diffY := b-0
    c:= float64(diffX) / float64(diffY)
    fmt.Println(c)
}

type Point struct{
    X int
    Y int
}

func getLinearParas(point1 Point, point2 Point)  {
    diffX := point1.X - point2.X
    diffY := point1.Y - point2.Y
    a := float64(diffX) / float64(diffY)
    fmt.Printf("diffY: %d; diffX:%d ; a:%f \n", diffY, diffX, a)
}
```

Like the code, If I put int values into a struct, and later apply division on them. the precision would be lost somehow.
The result of running above code is

```
 1.00000001053617 1.00000001053617
 1.00000001053617
 diffY: 94911150; diffX:94911151 ; a:1.000000
```

Or you can try it yourself in playground
https://play.golang.org/p/IDS18rfv9e6

Could anyone explain why this happens? and how to avoid such loss?
Thank you very much.

Comment: This has **absolutely** **nothing** to do with a struct. Nothing. The difference is Print**ln** vs Print**f** with a %f verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `%f` in the format string to `%v` or `%g` or `%.14f`. `fmt.Println` prints things with the equivalent of `%v`, `%v` for float64 is treated as `%g`. `%f` prints values with 6 significant digits by default, `%g` uses "the smallest number of digits necessary to identify the value uniquely".